# Amazon Redshift CREATE FUNCTION ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "default"

Tags: amazon-redshift, plpgsql, stored-functions

I am trying to create a function in Redshift through Aginity (v4.9.1.2686) and I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "default"

Function Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_columns (
    searchfield text,
    searchtables name[] default '{}',
    searchschema name[] default '{}')
RETURNS table(schemaname text, tablename text, columnname text, rowctid text)
AS $$
begin
    FOR schemaname, tablename, columnname IN
        SELECT c.table_schema, c.table_name, c.column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns c
        JOIN information_schema.tables t ON (t.table_name = c.table_name AND t.table_schema = c.table_schema)
        WHERE (c.table_name=ANY(searchtables) OR searchtables='{}')
        AND (c.table_schema=ANY(searchschema) OR searchschema='{}')
        AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text)=%L', schemaname, tablename, columnname, searchfield)
        INTO rowctid;
    IF rowctid IS NOT NULL 
        THEN RETURN NEXT;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

**EDIT**

Tried removing the defaults and get a different error:

> ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "table"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_columns (
    searchfield text,
    searchtables name[] ,
    searchschema name[] )
RETURNS table(schemaname text, tablename text, columnname text, rowctid text)
AS $$
begin
    FOR schemaname, tablename, columnname IN
        SELECT c.table_schema, c.table_name, c.column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns c
        JOIN information_schema.tables t ON (t.table_name = c.table_name AND t.table_schema = c.table_schema)
        WHERE (c.table_name=ANY(searchtables) OR searchtables='{}')
        AND (c.table_schema=ANY(searchschema) OR searchschema='{}')
        AND t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text)=%L', schemaname, tablename, columnname, searchfield)
        INTO rowctid;
    IF rowctid IS NOT NULL 
        THEN RETURN NEXT;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Redshift does not support default values for parameters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there a way I can get round this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Or can I just remove the default values? Or use something else?

Comment: Redshift also does not support functions returning sets: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there anyway in Redshift to get a function like this to work?

Comment: Your function looks a lot like a stored procedure. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html

Comment: See: [Overview of Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift also does not support functions returning sets: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html